# ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS not booting 32 bit

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

I'm using ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
when I boot the system I got a dialog box 
"the system is running in low-graphics mode"
I used tty Alt+ctrl+(F1-F6) do nothing
my machine is hp i5 pavilion g6

Answer (score -1):

This has worked for me before:

When at the low graphics screen, select the choice about the terminal.

Login with your account.

type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop && sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm`

after that, type `sudo reboot`